# 301 редирект дублей /, /?

Tags: redirect

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой редиректов дублей через .htaccess. Посмотрел похожие посты, но не нашел решения своей проблемы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать редирект:

- с `http://site.ru/index.php?blablabla` на `http://site.ru`
- с `http://site.ru/` на `http://site.ru`
- с `http://site.ru/?blablabla` на `http://site.ru`

Движок - modx Revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте на старом домене domain1.ua файл .htaccess, с содержанием:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

вариант 2

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/$
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain1.com/new-test/? [R=301,L]
```

и затем настроить перенаправление на хостинге

Comment: Это все один домен

Comment: @AlekseiSievriukov дописал